# spring add soap header to endpoint's response

Tags: java, spring, soap, response, endpoint

I have spring web service that have response message like this :

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns2:GetFlRpoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.example.com/siopso/schema">
             <ns2:ResponseInfo>
                <ns2:ResponseGenTime>2015-04-12T21:01:40.915+06:00</ns2:ResponseGenTime>
                <ns2:RequestID>549</ns2:RequestID>
                <ns2:Code>200</ns2:Code>
                <ns2:CodeDescription>Successful</ns2:CodeDescription>
             </ns2:ResponseInfo>
             <ns2:RPOInfo>
                <ns2:RPO>
                   <ns2:Barcode>XX780005595XX</ns2:Barcode>
                   <ns2:ReceptDate>2015-01-01+06:00</ns2:ReceptDate>
                   <ns2:Mailtype>Package</ns2:Mailtype>
                   <ns2:DelPostOffice>City19</ns2:DelPostOffice>
                   <ns2:Recipient>Someone1</ns2:Recipient>
                </ns2:RPO>
                <ns2:RPO>
                   <ns2:Barcode>XX183004561XX</ns2:Barcode>
                   <ns2:ReceptDate>2015-01-01+06:00</ns2:ReceptDate>
                   <ns2:Mailtype>Package2</ns2:Mailtype>
                   <ns2:DelPostOffice>City4</ns2:DelPostOffice>
                   <ns2:Recipient>Someone2</ns2:Recipient>
                   <ns2:RecipientAddr>Somewhere</ns2:RecipientAddr>
                </ns2:RPO>
             </ns2:RPOInfo>
             <ns2:FLRequestInfo>
                <ns2:Lastname>Ivanov</ns2:Lastname>
                <ns2:Firstname/>
                <ns2:Middlename/>
                <ns2:Barcode/>
                <ns2:FromDate>01.01.2015</ns2:FromDate>
                <ns2:ToDate>01.01.2015</ns2:ToDate>
             </ns2:FLRequestInfo>
          </ns2:GetFlRpoResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

For this response my endpoint `responsepayload` looks like this :

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "GetFlRpoRequest", namespace = FL_TARGET_NAMESPACE)
public @ResponsePayload GetFlRpoResponse getFlRpo(@RequestPayload GetFlRpoRequest request) {
    System.out.println("Get FL !");
    GetFlRpoResponse response = siopsoService.getFlRpo(request.getFLRequestInfo());
    return response;
}
```

And now I need to sign that response and add sign information into the header of response, and it must be like this:

```
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <SOAP-ENV:Header>
        <ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <ds:SignedInfo>
                <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315"/>
                <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311"/>
                <ds:Reference URI="#b0525e8a-dbcb-45da-abfd-d1bdecf6ccbb">
                    <ds:Transforms>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments"/>
                        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/>
                    </ds:Transforms>
                    <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34311"/>
                    <ds:DigestValue>valval=</ds:DigestValue>
                </ds:Reference>
            </ds:SignedInfo>
            <ds:SignatureValue>
                valuevalue==
            </ds:SignatureValue>
            <ds:KeyInfo>
                <ds:X509Data>
                    <ds:X509Certificate>
                        valuevaluevalue=
                    </ds:X509Certificate>
                </ds:X509Data>
            </ds:KeyInfo>
        </ds:Signature>
       </SOAP-ENV:Header>
       <SOAP-ENV:Body>
          <ns2:GetFlRpoResponse xmlns:ns2="http://webservices.example.com/siopso/schema">
             <ns2:ResponseInfo>
                <ns2:ResponseGenTime>2015-04-12T21:01:40.915+06:00</ns2:ResponseGenTime>
                <ns2:RequestID>549</ns2:RequestID>
                <ns2:Code>200</ns2:Code>
                <ns2:CodeDescription>Successful</ns2:CodeDescription>
             </ns2:ResponseInfo>
             <ns2:RPOInfo>
                <ns2:RPO>
                   <ns2:Barcode>XX780005595XX</ns2:Barcode>
                   <ns2:ReceptDate>2015-01-01+06:00</ns2:ReceptDate>
                   <ns2:Mailtype>Package</ns2:Mailtype>
                   <ns2:DelPostOffice>City19</ns2:DelPostOffice>
                   <ns2:Recipient>Someone1</ns2:Recipient>
                </ns2:RPO>
                <ns2:RPO>
                   <ns2:Barcode>XX183004561XX</ns2:Barcode>
                   <ns2:ReceptDate>2015-01-01+06:00</ns2:ReceptDate>
                   <ns2:Mailtype>Package2</ns2:Mailtype>
                   <ns2:DelPostOffice>City4</ns2:DelPostOffice>
                   <ns2:Recipient>Someone2</ns2:Recipient>
                   <ns2:RecipientAddr>Somewhere</ns2:RecipientAddr>
                </ns2:RPO>
             </ns2:RPOInfo>
             <ns2:FLRequestInfo>
                <ns2:Lastname>Ivanov</ns2:Lastname>
                <ns2:Firstname/>
                <ns2:Middlename/>
                <ns2:Barcode/>
                <ns2:FromDate>01.01.2015</ns2:FromDate>
                <ns2:ToDate>01.01.2015</ns2:ToDate>
             </ns2:FLRequestInfo>
          </ns2:GetFlRpoResponse>
       </SOAP-ENV:Body>
    </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

For this i've changed my responsepayload like this:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "GetFlRpoRequest", namespace = FL_TARGET_NAMESPACE)
    public @ResponsePayload GetFlRpoResponse getFlRpo(@RequestPayload DOMSource domSource,
            @RequestPayload GetFlRpoRequest request, SoapHeader header, MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("Get FL !");

        Provider kncaProvider = new IolaProvider();
        Security.addProvider(kncaProvider);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", kncaProvider.getName());

        ks.load(new FileInputStream(somekeyfile),somepass.toCharArray());

        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(somealias, somepass.toCharArray());

        ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(byteArrayOutputStream);
        TransformerFactory copyTransformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer copyTransformer = copyTransformerFactory.newTransformer();
        copyTransformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
        System.out.println(byteArrayOutputStream.toString());

        SaajSoapMessage soapResponse = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        header = soapResponse.getSoapHeader();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.newDocument();

        GetFlRpoResponse response = siopsoService.getFlRpo(request.getFLRequestInfo());

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(GetFlRpoResponse.class);
        Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
        m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
        m.marshal(response, document);

        SOAPHeaderElement headerElement = null;
          NodeList nodes = document.getElementsByTagNameNS
            ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Header");
          if(nodes.getLength() == 0)
          {
             System.out.println("Adding a SOAP Header Element");
             headerElement = document.createElementNS
               ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Header");
             nodes = document.getElementsByTagNameNS
              ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/","Envelope");
             if(nodes != null)
             {
                Element envelopeElement = (Element)nodes.item(0);
                headerElement.setPrefix(envelopeElement.getPrefix());
                envelopeElement.appendChild(headerElement);
             }
          }
          else
          {
             System.out.println("Found " + nodes.getLength() + " SOAP Header elements.");
             headerElement = (Element)nodes.item(0);
          }

        /*TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
        t.transform(source, result);*/

        XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(document, "", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311");
        headerElement.appendChild(sig.getElement());
        Transforms transforms = new Transforms(document);
        transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature");
        transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments");
        sig.addDocument("", transforms, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34311");
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate("somealias");
        sig.addKeyInfo(cert);
        sig.sign(privateKey);

        StringWriter os = new StringWriter();
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
        trans.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(os));
        os.close();
        System.out.println(os.toString());


        return response;
    }
```

But it didnt work. It responses soapfault with fault string:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Can someone show what I did wrong? I need to add that sign info to header of response message.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/soap/security/wss4j/Wss4jSecurityInterceptor.html

Comment: @KonstantinV.Salikhov did u read what i wrote? I dont need that interceptors because they dont include tag like <ds:X509Certificate> in <ds:X509Data>. And XWSS interceptor is the same! I need other solution like responsepayload changing.

Comment: @bakash_erni I strongly suggest a read of the documentation and how to configure it properly. The fact that most configuration show something else doesn't mean it cannot be done. You need to configure your security provider correctly.

Comment: @M.Deinum Anyway, the task that given to me was to add exactly the same header as I wrote above, not otherwise. I need only that header.

Comment: Again read the documentation...

Comment: @M.Deinum solved, answer is below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved the problem with custom SmartSoapEndpointInterceptor. I created MyCustomEndpointInterceptor that implements SmartSoapEndpointInterceptor and changed handleResponse for my needs.  Sourcecode is:

```
public class MyCustomEndpointInterceptor implements SmartSoapEndpointInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean handleRequest(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleResponse(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        SaajSoapMessage soapResponse = (SaajSoapMessage) messageContext.getResponse();
        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(strMsg);
        Document doc = soapResponse.getDocument();
        // Look for the SOAP header
        Element headerElement = null;
        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "Header");
        if (nodes.getLength() == 0) {
            System.out.println("Adding a SOAP Header Element");
            headerElement = doc.createElementNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "Header");
            nodes = doc.getElementsByTagNameNS("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "Envelope");
            if (nodes != null) {
                Element envelopeElement = (Element) nodes.item(0);
                headerElement.setPrefix(envelopeElement.getPrefix());
                envelopeElement.appendChild(headerElement);
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Found " + nodes.getLength() + " SOAP Header elements.");
            headerElement = (Element) nodes.item(0);
        }

        Provider kncaProvider = new IolaProvider();
        Security.addProvider(kncaProvider);

        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12", kncaProvider.getName());

        ks.load(new FileInputStream(keypath), keypass.toCharArray());

        PrivateKey privateKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(keyalias, keypass.toCharArray());

        XMLSignature sig = new XMLSignature(doc, "", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34310-gost34311");
        headerElement.appendChild(sig.getElement());
        Transforms transforms = new Transforms(doc); 
        transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature");
        transforms.addTransform("http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315#WithComments");
        sig.addDocument("", transforms,"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#gost34311"); 
        X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(somealias);
        sig.addKeyInfo(cert); 
        sig.sign(privateKey);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) throws Exception {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldIntercept(MessageContext messageContext, Object endpoint) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean understands(SoapHeaderElement header) {
        return true;
    }
}
```